# Is it permissible to use an umbrella on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, boneh-soter

Assuming one is inside an [eruv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruv) which generally permits transferring between domains on Shabbat, may one use an umbrella on Shabbat? If not, *why* not?

---

Follow-up question: What about other things that fold up/out (e.g. strollers, portable chairs, tables, or an [extendable canopy](http://retractablecanopies.tumblr.com))?

Comment: I've heard various reasons mentioned, such as *muktzah,* *melacha* of creating an *ohel,* and simply *minhag yisrael,* but don't know of any definitive answer.

Comment: There is a NEW invention: Shabbos umbrella “מגן השבת” For thousands of years, all Sabbath-keeping Jews in Israel and around the world walk in the rain on Shabbat without the protection of an umbrella, which is known to be forbidden to use on Shabbat. I invented a kosher umbrella for Shabbat that received the consent of the Chief Rabbi of Israel, and a wide range of dozens of important rabbis from all streams, from Israel from Europe and the United States – see the rabbis’ written consent, halakhic discussion and photos in the link below: https://shabbos-umbrella.netlify.app/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Opening an umbrella on Shabbat is [generally considered](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=3/25/2008) to be forbidden because of building.  The linked article notes that while the g'mara (not specifically cited) does permit opening a folding chair, even though that creates a "tent" over the ground below, the *purpose* of opening the chair isn't to create the tent, while the purpose of erecting a structure above oneself is:

> Accordingly, the Noda Be-Yehuda (work of responsa by Rabbi Yechezkel Landau of Prague, 1713-1793), among others, forbade opening umbrellas on Shabbat. This is the position taken by the vast majority of recent and contemporary authorities, as well, including Rabbi Moshe Halevi, in his work Menuchat Ahava, and Chacham Ovadia Yosef, in his work Yechaveh Da'at. It should be noted that once Halacha forbids opening an umbrella, closing an umbrella becomes forbidden, as well.

In addition, [this article notes that](http://torahmusings.com/2010/11/umbrellas-on-shabbat/)

> a chair folds and unfolds directly into the desired position. An umbrella, however, must be fastened or locked into place in order to assume the desired position. (Biur Halacha 315:7)

Comment: Additional details can be found at http://torahmusings.com/2010/11/umbrellas-on-shabbat/, and an overview of the process by which this ruling was accepted can be found at http://torahmusings.com/2012/08/umbrellas-on-shabbos/

Comment: I brought an umbrella on Monday that doesn't have to be locked.  You push a button, it opens. And clearly the intent when opening an umbrella is NOT to "build" anything.  You generally in point of fact open the thing hurriedly while exiting a door, simply to keep from getting soaked, not to build a tower of babel out of umbrellas.

Comment: @david - I don't remember where I read this, I think it was one of the links above, but umbrellas in the 1800's had to be locked to stay open. That is no longer true, but Halacha has a lot of inertia and is  resistant to change.

Comment: It should also be noted that some,rabbis permitted using an umbrella if it was opened and closed under an awning, since creating a tent under a tent is like doing nothing, and thus isn't prohibited.

Comment: @Shmuel Most umbrellas which I've seen need to be locked to stay open. Have you seen others?

Comment: @shmuel Brin you've never seen button umbrellas? Push a button it opens? Literally a category on Amazon. https://www.amazon.com/slp/one-button-umbrella/udnec493xu965ys. They do lock when you CLOSE it.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a bunch of people bring umbrellas to shul on Shabbat and leave them open during in the coat room during service. I know you're not supposed to open an umbrella on shabbat but there's a different rule for carrying an already open umbrella. If you open the umbrella before shabbat it's permissible in an erev. The [torahmusings link](http://torahmusings.com/2010/11/umbrellas-on-shabbat) suggests that you may give the appearance of breaking shabbat rules. That varies from shul to shul. In areas where it rains a lot, more observant people know the umbrella nuances.

Comment: If you could source your claim that there is a different rule for carrying an already open umbrella, that would make this answer more valuable.

Comment: @YEZ - Comments on the Torah Musings link (above, also [here](http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/08/umbrellas-on-shabbos/) ) mention that Chief Rabbi Jakobowitz permitted carrying already-open umbrellas on Shabbat.  Now if only I could find a reliable source to back up those comments...
<<||>>
Tatiana - Thank you for your answer.  Indeed, it appears logical to me that carrying an already-open umbrella should be fine, but I'm no rabbi.

Comment: This may be a case of "ignorance marit ayin". I.e., few people would know about this rule, and even if they did, I think most people would not know that the person carrying the umbrella had it opened prior to Shabbat. I think the *marit ayin* issue here may be a large factor. Re the last sentence, please explain how climate factors would influence things, here. If the umbrella is normally forbidden, what difference does the climate make?

Answer (score 1):

As far as a hood of a stroller, (or an extendable canopy) that was not left open even a little bit before shabbos, some Poskim rule that it is forbidden while others do permit it.

> The following Poskim explicitly rule this way (that it is forbidden): Ketzos Hashulchan 120 footnote 8 “Regarding the hood of strollers, it is obvious that it is forbidden to be opened on Shabbos even though it is attached to the stroller…One must warn the public regarding this.”; Igros Moshe 4:105; Sheivet Halevy 3:54; Or Letziyon 2:28-2; Halichos Olam 2:1; Minchas Yitzchak 10:26 leaves this matter in question although leans to be lenient in a case that the hood also forms side walls when opened.

See [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/opening-hood-of-stroller-on-shabbos/#_ftn15) and [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Infants_on_Shabbat#Cribs_.26_Strollers) for a full discussion and all the different opinions on the matter