# According to Conservative Judaism, is one permitted to use an umbrella on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, heterodox, boneh-soter

**According to Conservative Judaism**, may one use - unfold, carry, and refold - an umbrella in an eruv-enclosed area on Shabbat? What if it is not raining?

I would appreciate a link or quote from an official responsa or statement by a Conservative rabbinical body.

Related:  [Is it permissible to use an umbrella on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28860/is-it-permissable-to-use-an-umbrella-on-shabbat)

Comment: Good question (I don't understand why it was downvoted).  I didn't find it in a search of their responsa site, and Google led me to others who couldn't find it either.

Comment: It's not so clear that umbrellas on Shabbat are forbidden in orthodoxy! (They are, but...) The Chatam Sofer, for instance, ruled that it is permissible, because an umbrella is only a temporary structure. As the line in Conservative Judaism is to take advantage of all leniencies whenever possible, it seems like they would permit it. hettp://www.torahmusings.com/2010/11/umbrellas-on-shabbat/ http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=3/25/2008

Comment: @sam, see [this meta post on pluralism](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1298/472).  I think it's well-established that questions about Conservative Judaism are in-bounds on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @Tatpurusha - I am not sure that your statement that Conservative take advantage of all possible leniencies is correct.  I'd appreciate if you could provide a source.  Additional information about umbrellas and Shabbat can be found in the "related question" link.

Comment: Since the linked question doesn't specify "Orthodox Judaism", isn't this a dupe of that (proper subset)?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Technically, yes.  However, most people on this site seem to assume an Orthodox POV, so I feel a separate question explicitly stating a non-Orthodox POV is necessary.  (Not that it's entirely relevant, but I'm Orthodox, and assumed such as well.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4057/1713. That's about Rabbinic POV by default but the same might be true about Orthodox POV by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yehuda Wiesen wrote a "Guide to Practical Halacha and Home Ritual for Conservative Jews" (available [here](http://mahadash.com/docs/wiesen/halacha.htm)), from which I quote (from the section concerning Shabbat):

> There are many and various so called minor restrictions, some of which the Conservative
>   movement seems to follow and others that it does not. For example, Orthodox typically avoid
>   use of an umbrella on Shabbat due to the prohibitions against erecting a tent (in miniature), and
>   carrying (where there is no eruv). Although opening an umbrella does not seem to have been
>   formally addressed by the Law Committee, it appears to me that most (but not all)
>   Conservative Jews use umbrellas, sometimes reflecting lack of knowledge or concern but
>   sometimes reflecting the view that it is not really erecting a tent. The point here is that there are
>   many Shabbat restrictions and other laws that have not been addressed by the Law
>   Committee, and my observation of prevalent practice among some observant Conservative
>   Jews indicates an implied lenient halachic view concerning many practices. In this category I
>   would include tearing toilet paper and bathing, both forbidden by some but commonly done by
>   some observant Conservative Jews.

This guide was written in 1998 and last revised in 2004 according to its website, and I have found no evidence that the situation had changed since then.